# Set DNS subdomain manually

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, cname, httpd.conf

I am using the Zpanel v10.1.1 + CentOS 6.5 after setup all, I transfer all mysql databases, files and then domain. All working perfectly.
But I am stucked at subdomain, when we create a main domain it's possible create a DNS record for them but when I create a subdomain I am not able to create.

My subdomain not working: http://loja.genesiseries.com and http://forum.genesiseries.com
I am getting an error when I try to whois my DNS.

The main domain is obviosly genesiseries.com

my #grep named /var/log/messages

```
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: ----------------------------------------------------
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: ----------------------------------------------------
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: using up to 4096 sockets
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: listening on IPv4 interface venet0:0, 107.155.87.52#53
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: listening on IPv4 interface venet0:1, 107.155.87.60#53
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: sizing zone task pool based on 9 zones
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: using built-in DLV key for view _default
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'dynamic/managed-keys.bind'
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: couldn't add command channel 127.0.0.1#953: permission denied
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: couldn't add command channel ::1#953: permission denied
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone atrix-brasil.com/IN: loaded serial 2014122801
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone azbrasilreceptores.com/IN: loaded serial 2014122800
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone genesiseries.com/IN: loaded serial 2014123100
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 139
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone genesiseries.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2014123100)
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: running
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone atrix-brasil.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2014122801)
Dec 31 19:19:52 localhost named[536]: zone azbrasilreceptores.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2014122800)
Dec 31 19:21:37 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.6.20#54940: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:21:37 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.6.49#31648: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:23:30 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.16#50686: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:23:30 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.16#46422: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:23:30 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.23#39528: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:23:31 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.19#34967: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:25:33 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.5.176#35683: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:25:33 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.6.225#34248: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 19:25:38 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.6.150#36973: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:04:01 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.23#44938: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:04:01 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.18#48012: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:04:01 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.21#34375: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:04:01 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.23#44220: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:04:01 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.19#54421: query (cache) 'www.tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:31:17 localhost named[536]: client 66.249.66.159#37110: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 21:31:18 localhost named[536]: client 66.249.66.205#53959: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Dec 31 23:21:22 localhost named[536]: client 123.81.249.98#41112: query (cache) './A/IN' denied
Dec 31 23:21:22 localhost named[536]: client 123.81.249.98#41239: query (cache) './A/IN' denied
Dec 31 23:21:23 localhost named[536]: client 123.81.249.98#44311: notify question section contains no SOA
Dec 31 23:54:01 localhost named[536]: client 124.232.142.220#59575: query (cache) 'www.google.it/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 00:32:38 localhost named[536]: client 162.213.154.5#45619: query (cache) './ANY/IN' denied
Jan  1 00:32:38 localhost named[536]: client 162.213.154.5#45619: query (cache) './ANY/IN' denied
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: received SIGHUP signal to reload zones
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: sizing zone task pool based on 9 zones
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: using built-in DLV key for view _default
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: couldn't add command channel 127.0.0.1#953: permission denied
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: couldn't add command channel ::1#953: permission denied
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: reloading configuration succeeded
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: reloading zones succeeded
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: zone genesiseries.com/IN: loaded serial 2015010100
Jan  1 01:19:55 localhost named[536]: zone genesiseries.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2015010100)
Jan  1 01:35:42 localhost named[536]: client 223.220.250.33#50839: query (cache) './A/IN' denied
Jan  1 01:35:44 localhost named[536]: client 223.220.250.33#45782: query (cache) './A/IN' denied
Jan  1 01:35:44 localhost named[536]: client 223.220.250.33#40462: notify question section contains no SOA
Jan  1 01:55:15 localhost named[536]: client 220.165.13.144#45624: query (cache) './A/IN' denied
Jan  1 01:55:15 localhost named[536]: client 220.165.13.144#56223: query (cache) './A/IN' denied
Jan  1 08:26:57 localhost named[536]: client 124.232.142.220#38573: query (cache) 'www.google.com/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 08:49:59 localhost named[536]: client 107.182.19.66#42597: query (cache) 'rula.net/ANY/IN' denied
Jan  1 09:08:26 localhost named[536]: client 124.232.142.220#47675: query (cache) 'www.google.com/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 09:42:43 localhost named[536]: client 107.182.19.66#36192: query (cache) 'rula.net/ANY/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:05:22 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.5.155#49216: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:05:22 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.5.149#47893: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:07:27 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.6.225#25961: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:07:30 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.5.172#26472: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:11:12 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.5.173#27783: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:11:19 localhost named[536]: client 180.76.5.59#26296: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:58:24 localhost named[536]: client 66.249.66.59#45246: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 12:58:24 localhost named[536]: client 66.249.66.171#43125: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/A/IN' denied
Jan  1 15:23:40 localhost named[536]: shutting down
Jan  1 15:23:40 localhost named[536]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
Jan  1 15:23:40 localhost named[536]: no longer listening on 107.155.87.52#53
Jan  1 15:23:40 localhost named[536]: no longer listening on 107.155.87.60#53
Jan  1 15:23:40 localhost named[536]: exiting
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: starting BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 -u named
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: built with '--build=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-libtool' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--with-pic' '--disable-static' '--disable-openssl-version-check' '--with-dlopen=yes' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-postgres=yes' '--with-dlz-mysql=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-gssapi=yes' '--disable-isc-spnego' '--with-docbook-xsl=/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets' '--enable-fixed-rrset' 'build_alias=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS= -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' 'CPPFLAGS= -DDIG_SIGCHASE'

Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: ----------------------------------------------------
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: ----------------------------------------------------
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: listening on IPv4 interface venet0:0, 107.155.87.52#53
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: listening on IPv4 interface venet0:1, 107.155.87.60#53
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: sizing zone task pool based on 9 zones
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: using built-in DLV key for view _default
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'dynamic/managed-keys.bind'
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: couldn't add command channel 127.0.0.1#953: permission denied
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: couldn't add command channel ::1#953: permission denied
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan  1 15:23:49 localhost named[536]: zone atrix-brasil.com/IN: loaded serial 2014122801
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone azbrasilreceptores.com/IN: loaded serial 2014122800
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone genesiseries.com/IN: loaded serial 2015010100
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 159
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: running
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone azbrasilreceptores.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2014122800)
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone genesiseries.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2015010100)
Jan  1 15:23:50 localhost named[536]: zone atrix-brasil.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 2014122801)
Jan  1 15:55:36 localhost named[536]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: Unable to fetch DNSKEY set 'dlv.isc.org': SERVFAIL
Jan  1 16:23:36 localhost named[536]: client 212.83.152.146#5300: query (cache) 'isc.org/ANY/IN' denied
Jan  1 17:03:03 localhost named[536]: client 212.83.152.146#5305: query (cache) 'isc.org/ANY/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:17:36 localhost named[536]: client 54.193.160.62#26810: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/TXT/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:17:36 localhost named[536]: client 54.193.160.62#36347: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/MX/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:17:36 localhost named[536]: client 54.193.160.62#55264: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/MX/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:17:36 localhost named[536]: client 54.193.160.62#65117: query (cache) 'tabletgenesis.com.br/TXT/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:32 localhost named[536]: client 187.1.141.29#40821: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:32 localhost named[536]: client 187.1.141.29#35075: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:33 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.21#45545: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:33 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.16#45793: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:33 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.22#43063: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:33 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.22#63037: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
Jan  1 19:20:33 localhost named[536]: client 173.194.91.22#54291: query (cache) 'TABLETGENESIS.COM.BR/SOA/IN' denied
```

Which is the easiest way to create a DNS record for my subdomain?

Comment: @closetnoc Hey, are you here?

Comment: This is more a question for ServerFault than Webmasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, here is the solution. I have two:

First: Updating DNS manager by Zpanel, editing the main domain and in CNAME tab just add the new subdomain manually. It's normal doesn't show the subdomain on DNS management, just create a new CNAME entry, save and in SSH write:

```
php /etc/zpanel/panel/bin/daemon.php
```

This command will make your daemon run and update files.

Two: Updating manually

In your ssh, write

```
cd /etc/zpanel/configs/bind/zones/
ls
```

Now search for your domain file like domain.txt.com

```
vi domain.com.txt
```

This will open file editor, take careful in next step
You will see that file:

```
$TTL 10800
@ IN SOA ns1.domain.com.    postmaster.domain.com. (
    2015010202  ;serial
    21600    ;refresh after 6 hours
    3600    ;retry after 1 hour
    604800   ;expire after 1 week
    86400 )    ;minimum TTL of 1 day
@    3600    IN    A    100.101.10.11
mail    86400    IN    A    100.101.10.11
ns1    172800    IN    A    100.101.10.11
ns2    172800    IN    A    100.101.10.12
www    3600    IN    CNAME   @
ftp    3600    IN    CNAME   @
@    86400    IN    MX    10  mail.domain.com.
@    172800    IN    NS    ns1.domain.com.
@    172800    IN    NS    ns2.domain.com.
```

Press insert key
just add below FTP the lines:

```
subdomain1    86400    IN    CNAME   domain.com.
subdomain2    86400    IN    CNAME   domain.com.
```

now press Esc and write

> :wq

Now write

```
php /etc/zpanel/panel/bin/daemon.php
```

And you are done.
The first way will create the same entry on your txt file.